# Is it unprofessional to perform/dance in company annual function?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, offices

I have 1.5 yrs experience as a developer. I always had a zeal to perform on stage and I want to dance at this annual function.

But no one from our floor ever dances at such events.

**Will it be too unprofessional to dance where all of my other colleagues are senior. Should I move forward, give an audition and rock the stage :)**

Comment: Do they invite people to perform?

Comment: Don't care about those boring oldies, grab the opportunity to do what you enjoy. I don't see what is "unprofessional" about dancing at a company event, where (I assume) employees are expected to participate.

Comment: Do people from other parts of your organization (other than your floor) perform at the annual function?  It kind of blows my mind that that would be a possibility.

Comment: @Myles Yaa, they invite for  auditions and choreograph the good ones

Comment: Then go for it.   Audition.

Comment: @myles a division of my company located in India had a similar event to a talent show in the USA, but more as part of a big party event. Customs for this sort of thing vary around the world :-)

Comment: Also, I would recommend you [edit] to include your country as the answer to this is likely dependent on cultural factors.

Comment: As long as you don't do Elaine's Dance (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xi4O1yi6b0) you'll be fine.

Comment: You are allowed to dance any where, any time, as long as you dance the same way Elaine Bennis did in Seinfeld.

Comment: Thanks folks....The news i finally got selected for dance performance after auditions..

Answer (score 5):

If it is a company event, then by definition it isn't unprofessional. Assume that the rest of your floor just has stage fright.

Knock 'em dead, kid!

Answer (score -1):

If other employees from other departments do it, and if it is allowed/encouraged by the company, then go for it.

You might get some "funny" comments from your colleages the next day, but at least you had fun and did what you wanted.

Comment: But the thing i am worried about is that it should not affect my professional life.. i mean whatever status(very good professional ) i have right now in front of seniors

Comment: @koolomi I think you're overthinking this. As in most things in life, tough you think people will notice and care about whatever you're doing, they usually won't give a damn for more than five minutes. If you do your job well and act professionaly when you're working, I don't believe the old farts will care too much about what you do outside office hours.

Comment: @GustavoMP some cultures value this sort of thing a lot more than others. My Indian colleagues before would care 100x more about this than my US or European colleagues, because that status mattered way more to them professionally than it would have to me.